# SSH login fails after update/reboot on Ubuntu server 16.04 on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi

I don't have a monitor, so I'm trying to do this all over ssh.

I'm using the Ubuntu Classic Server 16.04 image from [Ubuntu Pi Flavor Maker](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/). I burn the SD card, ethernet the rpi to my wireless router, and then boot the rpi. I log in via ssh using username `ubuntu` and password `ubuntu` and then change the password. At that point I can do `sudo reboot` and in a few moments ssh back in using the new credentials.

However, after I install *aptitude* and run

```
aptitude update
aptitude upgrade
sudo reboot
```

I can't log back in via ssh. The rpi still finds the router and connects. I can ping the rpi and port 22 seems to be listening (see below). I just can't log back in.

Here are some diagnostics:

```
balter@BICB260:~$ sudo nmap -sS -Pn -p 22 192.168.1.5
Password:

Starting Nmap 7.50 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-06-25 13:19 PDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.5
Host is up (0.0013s latency).

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:04:4A:F0 (Raspberry Pi Foundation)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.37 seconds
balter@BICB260:~$ ping 192.168.1.5
PING 192.168.1.5 (192.168.1.5): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.990 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.528 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.085 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=2.024 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.5 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.528/1.907/2.085/0.221 ms
balter@BICB260:~$ ssh -vvv ubuntu@192.168.1.5
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/balter/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.5 [192.168.1.5] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.5 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.5 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: On the contrary, that looks like there is nothing listening on `tcp/22`.  Is the apt update disabling your ssh server?

Comment: Ok. I'm not super well versed on port scanning. I thought STATE=filtered meant listening. Is there a better command to use? Maybe not disabling, but perhaps not restarting. So I probably need to do \*something\* before rebooting to specify it get restarted.

Answer (score 1):

The TCP error "operation timed out" means that the client sent a TCP connection attempt to the server's IP address, but the server never responded. Common causes for this are:

1. Some kind of packet filter (aka a firewall) is blocking communication between the client and the server.
2. The server which you're trying to reach is down, disconnected from the network, or it's not using the IP address which you think it should be using.

[The nmap "filtered" state](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html) indicates that there is some kind of packet filter (aka a firewall) blocking your connection attempts:

> **filtered**
>   Nmap cannot determine whether the port is open because packet filtering prevents its probes from reaching the port. The
>   filtering could be from a dedicated firewall device, router rules, or
>   host-based firewall software. These ports frustrate attackers because
>   they provide so little information. Sometimes they respond with ICMP
>   error messages such as type 3 code 13 (destination unreachable:
>   communication administratively prohibited), but filters that simply
>   drop probes without responding are far more common.

Nmap says that the server is up and connected to the network. So the simplest explanation is that some kind of packet filter is blocking the SSH connection. If this was working before your ran aptitude, my guess is that aptitude might have installed, activated, and/or reconfigured a packet filter running on the Pi.

Another possibility might be that the Pi came up using the wrong IP address, or that it failed to configure its network interface properly and it doesn't have an IP address.

Comment: Could it be that some other device stole the IP, so the SSH goes to the wrong machine?? Is it possible to do an ARP and compare the MAC address?

Comment: It came up with the  same IP address as it did before. When it first boots, I can ping it (see output in question). But after a while, it disconnects. So the RPi is connecting to the router, but for some reason can't ssh back in.

Comment: @abalter That's all consistent with a packet filter/firewall blocking your connection attempts.

Comment: So, is this something I could fix in a configuration before rebooting? It is clearly something that happened during the update/upgrade.